# How to disable iWork Number formulas localization with changing system locale?

Tags: localization, osx-mavericks, iwork

I've got localized Mavericks, and I'm not able to change its locale, because of some specific circumstances. Everything seems to be ok accept one thing. iWork Numbers formulas localization is a real pain. Is there any way to get their english names without switching entire system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I’ve got my own tricky solution. Localization file replacement. TSCalculationEngine.strings is responsible for Numbers.app calculation mechanism localization. You can replace it with english version.

Open Terminal.app and run following:

```
cd /Applications/Numbers.app/ # Where is you Numbers.app located?
cd Contents/Resources/
cd ru.lproj # Your localization path
ln -F -s ../en.lproj/TSCalculationEngine.strings .
```

Wuala! You’ve got English formulas in a Russian Numbers.app.
You have to redo it after application update I guess.